# Who communicate on a private ethereum network?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, hosting

I'm new to Go-Ethereum (GETH) and would like to ask a question that may seem quite dumb.

Let's say that I create my own private ethereum blockchain with GETH (I created accounts, the genesis block...), and deployed a Dapp trought it.

I would like to know if I were to use the JSON-RPC server, can I use this Dapp even if I'm not connected to the same local network as the node running the server?

If not how I can deploy a private ethereum network where people I have chosen and are located all over the world can use my Dapp ?

Thanks in advance to anybody that may help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of any Ethereum-based network, quite literally, as a collection of independently running pieces of software spread across the world. They are 'sending messages' to each other in a certain agreed-upon format. The 'agreed-upon' format is called the protocol which is a set of rules for forming the messages.

In order for any particular Ethereum-based network to identify other members of the same network, all the members of that network need to be configured in the same way.

If you run Geth and configure it (either through config files or command line options) for the Ethereum mainnet, then it will send and receive messages on the mainnet.

If you configure Geth to join one of the testnets, then it will join that testnet.

There's no 'cross-talk' between network because Geth is either configured properly to communicate on a network or it's not. If Geth is not configured properly for mainnet, then it will join a different network (but only if there's anyone out there listening...)

In your case, you want to get all the "people you have chosen" to configure their Geth instances to communicate on your network.

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to dig into the details of configuring Geth. That's definitely documented online. Look for "Setting up a private Ethereum network."

Comment: I understand now ! Thank you very much for your explanation :) !

Comment: Glad I could help.